# How to trigger aria-activedescendant repeatedly

Tags: filter, accessibility, dropdown

Hi I'm doing an accessible  Dropdown that is able to filter the options. Everytime entering an input (handleOnChange), the screen reader shall read the first option element that is filtered. Here I use aria-activedescendant at input to point to the option ID. However, the screen reader will only read the option once, only when the aria-activedescendant change, then screen reader will read the new element that is selected. Is there any way to keep on triggering aria-activedescendant to force screen reader keep on reading the same element it is pointing to?

Comment: could you put a quick fiddle together that replicates the problem - at the moment it is difficult to understand exactly how the filter mechanism you created works and if the first element should indeed be read over and over or if that is just a misunderstanding on how screen readers are meant to behave.

Comment: Thus us the url :https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-2x93b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark    it's a dropdown that we can hear the options that are selected through input typing, but I would like the screen reader to keep on reading the options ex: when I type "arge", it will still read "argentina", the item selected.